# Replace xml tag with regex

Tags: c#, xml, regex

How can I replace a certain part in a xml file with a definied string?

```
<tag1></tag2>
<tag2></tag2>
...etc
<soundcard num=0> 
<name>test123</name>
</soundcard>
<soundcard num=1> 
<name>test123</name>
</soundcard>
<soundcard num=2> 
<name>test123</name>
</soundcard>
<tag5></tag5>
```

replace all soundcard parts that the result looks like that:

```
<tag1></tag2>
<tag2></tag2>
...etc
{0}
<tag5></tag5>
```

I'm using c# .net 3.5 and I thougt of a regex solution

Comment: No *not* use regular expressions to parse, modify or otherwise handle XML and other non-regular languages (such as HTML, JSON, YAML, ...).

The proper solution here is to use the XML APIs to parse and alter the document tree however you like.

Comment: @Johannes: You mean _Do_ not.

Comment: [DO NOT PARSE XML USING Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)!

Comment: It's remarkable how many people try to parse XML/HTML with regex...

Comment: @SLaks: Argh, yes; too late to fix a typo now, though.

Answer (score 3):

If it *has* to be a regex, your XML file is well-formed, and you *know* (say, from the DTD) that `<soundcard>` tags can't be nested, then you can use

```
(<soundcard.*?</soundcard>\s*)+
```

and replace all with `{0}`.

In C#:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(<soundcard.*?</soundcard>\s*)+", "{0}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

For a quick-and-dirty fix to a one-off problem, I think that's OK. It's not OK to think of regex as the proper tool to handle XML in general.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use Linq to XML and remove the entities and replace it with a Text Node.

**Update Apr 16/2010 4:40PM MST**

Here's an example of Linq to XML, I'm a bit rusty but it should at least give you an idea of how this is done.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("myxml.xml");

var soundcards = select el from root.Elements() where el.Name == "soundcard" select el;
var prev_node = soundcards.First().PreviousNode;

// Remove Nodes
foreach(XElement card in soundcards)
    card.Remove();

// Build your content here into a variable called newChild

prev_node.AddAfterSelf(newChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use an XSLT transformation to replace the tags you want to replace with a known tag, say , and then String.Replace('', '{0}');.

I echo what Johannes said, do NOT try to build REs to do this. As your XML gets more complex, you error rate will increase.